# Clicking cancel when entering values in inputbox not exiting procedure

Tags: delphi

I use an inputbox in my project to get data to input into a database. The problem is that if the user clicks cancel on the input box it takes the default value in the inputbox. How can I exit the procedure if cancel is clicked? This is how my inputbox looks:

```
sTeamName := inputbox('Team Name','Enter a team name','Phillies');
```

Here if the user were to click cancel, sTeamName will = 'Phillies'. I can't validate that the default value is stored in the variable, because the default value is possibly what the user wants to enter. Is there like a if inputbox.cancel.click exit or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [`InputQuery`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Dialogs.InputQuery) function instead. This returns a boolean which is `False` [iff](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/iff) the dialog was cancelled, and saves the input string in a `var` parameter:

```pascal
var
  S: string;
begin
  S := 'My New Team';
  if InputQuery('Team Name', 'Enter a team name:', S) then
    ShowMessageFmt('You entered "%s".', [S]);
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do it with an inputbox, or is an inputquery the only way?

Comment: @OdinMostert: Why do you not want to use the `InputQuery` function? IMHO, the `InputBox` function is simply an example of very poor design -- you must be able to determine if a dialog box was cancelled, and `InputBox` won't tell you this.

Comment: Reason I wanted a solution using inputboxes was because my program has like 20 + times where I already coded a solution using an inputbox. But if you say that there is no way to determine if cancel is clicked with it I will switch to InputQuery.

Comment: @Odin: Yes, switching to `InputQuery` is definitely the right thing to do.

Comment: @OdinMostert "*if ... there is no way to determine if cancel is clicked with [InputBox] I will switch to InputQuery*" - there IS a way, you are just refusing to use it - using a more sensible `ADefault` parameter value. But I agree with Andreas, `InputQuery()` will suit your needs better than `InputBox()` does.

Comment: @OdinMostert Sometimes we spend a lot of time writing code that turns out to be bad.  Better to [fix it sooner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt) rather than live with it until it gets bigger and uglier.  Often the best answer is just to let that crufty old code go - don't get attached to it just because you spent a lot of time on it.  Get attached to good, clean code that works well instead.

Answer (score 0):

> if the user clicks cancel on the input box it takes the default value in the inputbox

That is by design, and is [documented behavior](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Dialogs.InputBox):

> **If the user chooses the Cancel button, InputBox returns the default value.** If the user chooses the OK button, InputBox returns the value in the edit box.

---

> I can't validate that the default value is stored in the variable, because the default value is possibly what the user wants to enter.

Use a blank string for the default instead, eg:

```pascal
sTeamName := InputBox('Team Name', 'Enter a team name', '');
if sTeamName <> '' then begin
  // use sTeamName as needed...
end else
begin
  // cancelled, do something else
end;
```

Otherwise, use [`InputQuery()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Dialogs.InputQuery) instead, as shown in [@AndreasRejbrand's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68776309/65863). The documentation states:

> Use the InputBox function when there is a default value that should be used when the user chooses the Cancel button (or presses Esc) to exit the dialog. **If the application needs to know whether the user chooses OK or Cancel, use the [InputQuery](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Dialogs.InputQuery) function instead**.

Comment: Yea I know it is easy to have a blank string as default value, but I use the default value in my program to guide the end user on what to enter. It is mostly used as example data.

Comment: `InputBox()` can't differentiate between the initial value supplied on enter vs the default value returned on exit, so you could move the initial value into the `Prompt` parameter instead, eg: `sTeamName := InputBox('Team Name', 'Enter a team name, ie Phillies', '');` Otherwise, use `InputQuery()`.